# object.style.display throwing message error on console

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, bootstrap-4

UPDATE so here is a better code for you. I cut it down to have only what's strictly necessary for you to reproduce the problem.

```js
// change the color of the button when mousedown/up

let button = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
  for(i = 0; i < button.length; i++){
    button[i].onmousedown = function() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "#a3a3a3";
    };

    button[i].onmouseup = function() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "#808080";
    };
}

let buttonLg = document.getElementsByClassName('button-lg');
  for(i = 0; i < buttonLg.length; i++){
    buttonLg[i].onmousedown = function() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "#a3a3a3";
    };

    buttonLg[i].onmouseup = function() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "#808080";
    };
}

let button2 = document.getElementsByClassName('button2');
  for(i = 0; i < button2.length; i++){
    button2[i].onmousedown = function() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "#ffe299";
    };

    button2[i].onmouseup = function() {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "#ffca47";
    };
}

// show the numbers typed or result

let result = document.getElementById('result');

let preview = [];


let buttonAc = document.getElementById('ac');
let plusMinus = document.getElementById('plus-minus');
let plusMinus2 = document.getElementById('plus-minus2');

let buttonN7 = document.getElementById('seven');
let buttonN72 = document.getElementById('seven2');
let buttonN8 = document.getElementById('eight');
let buttonN82 = document.getElementById('eight2');
let buttonN9 = document.getElementById('nine');
let buttonN92 = document.getElementById('nine2');


// button AC erasing result and changing outlook to C when other buttons are clicked
// number 0 disapear when there is only zero and when a key is clicked

buttonAc.onclick = function () {
  buttonAc.innerHTML = "AC";
  preview = [];
  result.innerHTML = 0;
}

// concatenation of the buttons numbers without any commas

buttonN7.onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('ac').innerHTML = "C";
  buttonN7 = 7;
  preview.push(buttonN7);
  const a = preview.join('');
  result.innerHTML = a;
}

buttonN8.onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('ac').innerHTML = "C";
  buttonN8 = 8;
  preview.push(buttonN8);
  const a = preview.join('');
  result.innerHTML = a;
}

buttonN9.onclick = function () {
  document.getElementById('ac').innerHTML = "C";
  buttonN9 = 9;
  preview.push(buttonN9);
  const a = preview.join('');
  result.innerHTML = a;
}

// positive to negative value and vice versa with the plus, minus key

plusMinus.onclick = function(){

  let a = preview.join('');
  let b = parseInt(a, 10);
  let c = b * -1;

  result.innerHTML = c;
  plusMinus.style.display = "none";
  plusMinus2.style.display = "block";

  //this code below works
  //document.getElementById('nine').style.display = "none";
  
  //that one does not work
  buttonN9.style.display = "none";
  
  buttonN92.style.display = "block";
}

plusMinus2.onclick = function(){

  let a = preview.join('');
  let b = parseInt(a, 10);
  let c = b * -1;

  result.innerHTML = b;
  plusMinus2.style.display = "none";
  plusMinus.style.display = "block";
}

buttonN92.onclick = function(){
  result.innerHTML = 0;
  preview = [];
  
  //this code below works
  //document.getElementById('nine').style.display = "block";
  
  //that one does not work
  buttonN9.style.display = "block";
  
  buttonN92.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
h1 {
  padding: 30px;
}

.result {
  font-size: 80px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  color: #f9f9f9;
  padding-right: 20px;
  background-color: #696969;
}

.row1 {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.button,
.button2,
.button-lg {
  width: 25%;
}

p {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#ac,
#plus-minus,
#plus-minus2,
#percentage,
#seven,
#eight,
#nine,
#seven2,
#eight2,
#nine2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: #808080;
  color: #f9f9f9;
  height: 140px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-right: 1px solid #696969;
}

#ac,
#plus-minus,
#percentage,
#seven,
#eight,
#nine {
  display: block;
}

#plus-minus2,
#seven2,
#eight2,
#nine2 {
  display: none;
}

#division,
#multiplication{
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: #ffca47;
  color: #f9f9f9;
  height: 140px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Calculator</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="text-center">Calculator</h1>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12">
          <h5 id="result" class="card-title text-right result">0</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12">
          <div class="card-group row1">
            <p id="ac" class="card-text text-center button">AC</p>
            <p id="plus-minus" class="card-text text-center button">+ | -</p>
            <p id="plus-minus2" class="card-text text-center button">+ | -</p>
            <p id="percentage" class="card-text text-center button">%</p>
            <p id="division" class="card-text text-center button2">/</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-12">
          <div class="card-group row2">
            <p id="seven" class="card-text text-center button">7</p>
            <p id="seven2" class="card-text text-center button">7</p>
            <p id="eight" class="card-text text-center button">8</p>
            <p id="eight2" class="card-text text-center button">8</p>
            <p id="nine" class="card-text text-center button">9</p>
            <p id="nine2" class="card-text text-center button">9</p>
            <p id="multiplication" class="card-text text-center button2">X</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So here is the idea: It's a calculator, so I opened my calculator from my iMac and I just checked the behavior to try to reproduce it.

What you can do:
- clicking on the number, showing them on the screen result.
- Clicking on AC make the button change to C and clear the screen result.
- Clicking on %, / and X makes nothing yet. 
- Clicking on "+|-" swap the number to it's minus.

Here is what I'm trying to do. Normally, when you click the "+|-" key several time, it's going from negative to positive etc. ... and, normally if you click on a number it should go back to 0. I tried first with an external button to test and then I used the key 9 to see if it will work fine, with that code here:

```js
document.getElementById('nine').style.display = "block"; //or none
```

It works perfectly! But, when I throw that code instead (I marked them up on the whole snippet to you identify them better)

```js
buttonN9.style.display = "block"; //or none
```

BADABOOM, red alert on the console.

I've tried everything on every sens since hours; return my brain as much as I can; I'm still doing it. This evening, I must go somewhere with my wife. It's going to be hard to not think about it.

I will be honest with you, the calculator from the iPhone does not have the same behavior. If you fire 1,2,3 then +|- it goes -123. If you fire again 7, it goes -1237. So, maybe I mess up my brain too much, but I want to do it :)

Comment: Your code is correct. You probably is calling the JS before the DOM is loaded.

Comment: I'm not sure how you created that snippet, but you ended up with two snippets overlapping each other. When I fix that, the code works (of course). Please update the question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @Azametzin - That would be a different error, not the error the OP quoeted.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Not necessarily. It was an assumption and usually when it returns undefined that is one of the reasons.

Comment: The name of the function the error occurred in, `HTMLParagraphElement.plusMinus.onclick` suggests that possibly, your real code uses `this.style.display = "none";` and `this` isn't what you expect it to be. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work).

Comment: @Azametzin - Yes, necessarily. :-) If it were before the button exists in the DOM, the error would be accessing `style` on `null`, not accessing `display` on `undefined`.

Comment: True. Didn't read all of it.

Comment: Yes i see what you mean @T.J.Crowder ! I'm gone check right now ! Thanks guys ! I updated a bit ...

Comment: @Azametzin nope sir. My js is at the end :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what do you mean by "I'm not sure how you created that snippet" I'm beginner so i'm just trying to build something to get experience and earn knowledges :) Your comment is more negative or positive ? haha ! Just to know, then i can learn from my mistakes :)

Comment: @JeremyBertin - I meant it literally. If you use the Create Snippet dailog box, it doesn't do what was in your question, so...

Comment: @JeremyBertin - Your update does not provide a [mcve]. Please read the link and provide an MCVE. That's the only way we'll be able to help you, other than to say: Clearly, one of those variables refers to something that is not a DOM element.

Comment: So when i trigger "plusMinus" the line where there is "buttonN9.style.display = "none";" is throwing red at the console. Does not matter, where i put that line ...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i see and i'm already thankful for your help ! I'm not used of all terms sorry ... I have the project on Github, i'm gone throw what i have done since and put it here maybe ? Thanks again :)

Comment: @JeremyBertin - No, don't post all of your code. Please. Read. The. Link: [mcve]

Comment: @Jeremy, have you tried giving an **initial** inline or external css display style of `block` to your button, before applying Javascript?

Comment: @Crowder is right. Also, these codes should be entered using inline code botton with the `{}` symbol. You should only use the code snippet button (`<>`) for complete runnable codes.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you have a link for the repository if you want :)

Comment: @UdoE. yes sir, it's initialise at my CSS folder :) Is that repository will help better maybe ? https://github.com/jeanjacquesaka1980/calculator

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i've checked thousand times (maybe more) and all that variables refers to something that is a DOM element ... Will check again and again, i hope i've made a stupid mistake ...

Comment: The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. **Again**, please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well ... i see always many guys put in jsfiddle link so ... i'm gone do it on next week only :) Anyway, thanks for your help ^^

Answer (score 0):

Simply put all your code that accesses the DOM in a `window.onload()` handler, like this:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {

        let plusMinus = document.getElementById('plus-minus');
        let buttonN9 = document.getElementById('nine');
        // other variable initialization 

        plusMinus.onclick = function() { 

            buttonN9.style.display = "none"; 
            // other handler code logic
        }

        // other event handlers
    };
</script>
```

This way, you are sure the DOM is ready before accessing or manipulating it.

Also, from the html file in your Github repository [here](https://github.com/jeanjacquesaka1980/calculator/blob/master/calculator/index.html); you included several external scripts (including jquery) **after** your script. Except these scripts depend on your own script - which is not likely, you should always place your own script **last** after other external scripts that your code may likely depend on.

**UPDATE**: There are issues with firing window.onload from within the `body` tag. see the answer on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload). In addition to my previous answer, try putting your scripts in the `header` tag like this:

```
<head>
    <!-- Place other external scripts here -->
    <script src='myscript.js'></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Let's try this and thanks a lot ! If it's not working again, i will provide a nice code with a nice description for everybody :)

Comment: So, it's not working, let me provide something good :) But much respect and thanks for your help

Comment: @Jeremy, did you see my update to the answer with regards to script placement?

Comment: @JeremyBertin, you can also push your changes to github, so i see them. thanks

Comment: @JeremyBertin, i just corrected the code: change `window.onload(function...` to `window.onload = function...`.

Comment: yes i'm gone try all your tricks ! Everything is on Github but i just drop a smaller code here :) Many many thanks ! Much appreciated !

Comment: I've tried the script, totaly at the end ... does not work :/

Comment: @JeremyBertin, I'm on my mobile device right now. it will take me awhile until evening to get to my PC. Maybe then i can reproduce your calculator on my computer and get it working. Thanks

Comment: So then i must find before you ! Haha ! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

So, here is the solution. As a beginner, i made first some mistakes, i was repeating the functions. I've created for each behavior one function. The main problem is i wanted to get to an index thru an array without using any loop. The loop for made the deal and now it's behaving as i want ...

The list of the buttons did not change. What you have:
- A function to handle a reset button.
- A function to handle the value of the numbers buttons
- A function to the positive/negative number
- A function to reset the positive/negative number in case you click on one number.

This is how behave the calculator that i have so i'm just trying to do the exactly same thing. Thanks a lot for your help !

```js
function buttonResetHandler(button){
  button.onclick = function (){
    button.innerHTML = "AC";
    preview = [];
    result.innerHTML = 0;
  }
}

buttonResetHandler(buttonAc);

// concatenation of the buttons numbers without any commas

function buttonNumberHandler(button, value){
  button.onclick = function(){
    buttonAc.innerHTML = "C";
    button = value;
    preview.push(button);
    const a = preview.join('');
    result.innerHTML = a;
  }
}

buttonNumberHandler(buttonN0, 0);
buttonNumberHandler(buttonN1, 1);
buttonNumberHandler(buttonN2, 2);
buttonNumberHandler(buttonN3, 3);
buttonNumberHandler(buttonN4, 4);
buttonNumberHandler(buttonN5, 5);
buttonNumberHandler(buttonN6, 6);
buttonNumberHandler(buttonN7, 7);
buttonNumberHandler(buttonN8, 8);
buttonNumberHandler(buttonN9, 9);


// positive to negative value and vice versa with the plus, minus key

function buttonPlusMinusHandler(button1, button2, button3, button4){
  button1.onclick = function(){

    let a = preview.join('');
    let b = parseInt(a, 10);
    let c = b * -1;

    result.innerHTML = c;
    button1.style.display = "none";
    button2.style.display = "block";
    for(i = 0; i < button3.length; i++){
      button3[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    for(i = 0; i < button4.length; i++){
      button4[i].style.display = "block";
    }

    if(result.innerHTML == c){
      button2.onclick = function(){
        result.innerHTML = b;
        button2.style.display = "none";
        button1.style.display = "block";
        }
      }
    }
  }

buttonPlusMinusHandler(plusMinus, plusMinus2, allButtonsN, allButtonsN2);

function buttonNumberResetPlusMinus(button, button2){
  for(i = 0; i < button.length; i++){
    button[i].onclick = function(){
      preview = [];
      result.innerHTML = 0;
      for(i = 0; i < button2.length; i++){
        button[i].style.display = "none";
        button2[i].style.display = "block";
      }
    }
  }
}

buttonNumberResetPlusMinus(allButtonsN2, allButtonsN);
```